# Targeting parent classes and adding a class to them

Tags: jquery, html, css

Simply put I have one menu, sub-menu and sub-submenu so to speak and rhe sub-submenu has active link with a class of .current-menu-item . Now I want to traverse upward in the DOM finding it's parent .menu-item-has-children and its parent  .menu-item-has-children and add a class to both of them .current-menu-sub.

```
$(".sidebar li.current-menu-item").parents().hasClass('menu-item-has-children') {
  $('.menu-item-has-children').addClass("current-menu-sub");
};
```

This is my code, but somethings quite not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close but `hasClass` is not a dom searching function

You just need to pass the parents selector(s) to `parents()`

```
$(".sidebar li.current-menu-item")
        .parents('.menu-item-has-children')
        .addClass("current-menu-sub");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a selector in [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) and apply `.addClass()` to all of those that match by chaining that method to it:

```
$(".sidebar li.current-menu-item").parents('.menu-item-has-children')
                                  .addClass("current-menu-sub");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the`'.menu-item-has-children'` parent selector to `parents()`

```
$(".sidebar li.current-menu-item").parents('.menu-item-has-children').addClass("current-menu-sub");
```